Stage and jobs blocks breaks gitlab CI with "configuration is invalid: jobs jobs config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword"
.gitlab-ci.yml with
stages:
  - test

jobs:
  lint:
    stage: test
    image: python:3.8  # Assuming same image for both jobs
    script:
      - pip install black
      - black --check .  
    allow_failure: false 

  testcov:
    stage: test
    image: python:3.8
    script:
      - pip install pytest pytest-cov
      - pytest --cov api/
      - curl -Os https://cli.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
      - chmod +x codecov
      - ./codecov upload-process -t $CODECOV_TOKEN

fails with
This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs jobs config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

However the same without jobs and stages is valid and works
lint:
  image: python:3.8  # Assuming same image for both jobs
  script:
    - pip install black
    - black --check .  
  allow_failure: false 

testcov:
  image: python:3.8
  script:
    - pip install pytest pytest-cov
    - pytest --cov api/
    - curl -Os https://cli.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
    - chmod +x codecov
    - ./codecov upload-process -t $CODECOV_TOKEN

is there something that missing in stages version of code?

In  GitLab CI version 13.0 and later, the script keyword should be nested within a before_script or after_script section e.g. for the code above the middle must be replaced with
  before_script:
    - pip install black
  script:
    - black --check .
  allow_failure: false 

testcov:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.8
  before_script:
    - pip install pytest pytest-cov

